# parallel foreach and SyncLock does not work in target cpu x86

Tags: vb.net

I used `Parallel ForEach` and `SyncLock` in VB.Net.

Here is my code :

```
Parallel.ForEach(Collection, Sub(p)
     'do something 
     If List.Any(Function(x) x.Field1 = headers(0)) Then
          SyncLock _SyncObject
               Dim current = List.First(Function(x) x.Field1 = headers(0))
               'do something
          End SyncLock

     End If
End Sub)
```

This code executes successfully in OS 64 bit. But in OS 32 bit, it does not work.

The code throws an exception, which occurs in the dataset designer :

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

The exception occurs in here :

```
   <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(),  _
     Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")>  _
    Public Property FromMVar() As String
        Get
            Try 
                **Return CType(Me(Me.tablemyTable.Field1Column),String)**
            Catch e As Global.System.InvalidCastException
                Throw New Global.System.Data.StrongTypingException("The value for column 'Field1' in table 'myTable' is DBNull.", e)
            End Try
        End Get
        Set
            Me(Me.tableLinesFile.FromMVarColumn) = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

I tried with all the state of target cpu (86 , 64 , any cpu ). What can I do to fix this problem on OS 32?

Comment: There is at least one threading race bug clearly evident, there's probably more than one.  When List.Any() returns True and you *then* take a lock then you don't have any guarantee that List.Any() is *still* True.  You have to move the List.Any() call inside the SyncLock statement as well.  Which completely defeats the point of using Parallel of course.

Comment: What is difference between 32 and 64 ? Why it works in OS 64 ?

Comment: Threading race bugs have a strong knack for hiding themselves, they are heavily timing-dependent.  And 64-bit code does not run the same way as 32-bit code, it is generally a bit slower.  That does *not* mean that the bug is not there, it just means that you haven't tested long enough yet.  Some race bugs strike only once a month, *very* hard to diagnose.